# import path for swift shebang scripts

Tags: swift, import, include-path, shebang

What is the set of `import` paths for some swift ExampleSript.swift shebang script on linux, macos, and windows? Can this import search set be modified in|by the shell runtime environment, or from the command line which launches the script?

```swift
#!/usr/bin/swift
import WhereCanIBeFound
```

```swift
#!/usr/bin/env swift
import WhereCanIBeFound
```